# Nagios web interface isn't using the configuration files

Tags: monitoring, nagios

I want put my own configuration in the Nagios Core 4.3.4.

I have the following setting in Nagios:

- /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg

  ```
  cfg_file=/usr/local/nagios/etc/objects/newhost.cfg
  cfg_dir=/usr/local/nagios/etc/servers
  ```
- /usr/local/nagios/etc/servers/ubuntu_host.cfg

  ```
  define host {
      use                          linux-server
      host_name                    ubuntu_host
      alias                        Ubuntu Host
      address                      192.168.1.10
      register                     1
  }
  ```
- /usr/local/nagios/etc/objects/newhost.cfg

  ```
  # Define a host for the local machine
  define host{
      use                     linux-server
      host_name               google.com
      alias                   google.com
      address                 www.google.com
  }

  # Define a service to "ping" the local machine
  define service{
      use                     generic-service
      host_name               google.com
      service_description     PING
      check_command           check_ping!100.0,20%!500.0,60%
  }

  define service{
      use                     generic-service
      host_name               google.com
      service_description     HTTP
      check_command           check_http
      notifications_enabled   0
  }
  ```

The configuration validation is OK and it display 3 hosts:

```
Running pre-flight check on configuration data...
Checking objects...
    Checked 7 services.
    Checked 3 hosts.
    Checked 0 host groups.
    Checked 0 service groups.
    Checked 1 contacts.
    Checked 1 contact groups.
    Checked 24 commands.
    Checked 5 time periods.
    Checked 0 host escalations.
    Checked 0 service escalations.
Checking for circular paths...
    Checked 3 hosts
    Checked 0 service dependencies
    Checked 0 host dependencies
    Checked 5 timeperiods
Checking global event handlers...
Checking obsessive compulsive processor commands...
Checking misc settings...
Total Warnings: 0
Total Errors:   0
```

I restarted nrpe service, nargios service and httpd service.

But Nargios Web Interface display the same information.
[image: List of hosts in Nagios Web Interface]

[image: List of services in Nagios Web Interface]

Comment: I have stopped all services.
I have only started httpd service and nagios web interface display "Daemon running with PID 2097" but this PID not exist in the machine.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late but I just encountered this today. but it seems after doing a few `git push` and `git pull` my `chmod` for `/usr/local/nagios/var/objects.cache` was changed to root instead of nagios.

I used  `ls -al /usr/local/nagios/var` to check the timestamps and noticed this.

The solution for me was:

`cd /usr/local/nagios/var/`

`chown nagios:nagios objects.cache`

`systemctl restart nagios`

`systemctl restart httpd`

I got reference from [https://support.nagios.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=52727&p=276428&hilit=objects.cache+and+retention.dat#p276428](https://support.nagios.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=52727&p=276428&hilit=objects.cache%20and%20retention.dat#p276428)